# How can I uninstall Ubuntu when dual-booted?

Tags: uninstall

I've been deciding on whether to install Ubuntu and keep it as dual-boot, or to only use Windows, and I need to know how to uninstall Ubuntu and keep Windows alone, with all my Windows data left on the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OS-Uninstaller or you can do manually

How to using OS Uninstaller https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller

also see windows 7 or 8 in this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader